# Create menu from array which can be hooked up from anywhere on the script

Tags: php, arrays

I' am trying to make a menu something like WordPress does but in more simple way. In WordPress you can hook up Admin sidebar menu from any php scripts, thats what I' am trying to do.

**This are all the array that contains the menu information**

```
$admin_menu_page = array();
    $admin_submenu_page = array();

    $admin_menu_page[] = array("Dashboard", "dashboard");
    $admin_menu_page[] = array("Pages", "pages");
    $admin_menu_page[] = array("Setings", "setings");

    $admin_submenu_page['dashboard'] = array("Home", "home");
    $admin_submenu_page['dashboard'] = array("Update", "update");

    $admin_submenu_page['pages'] = array("Add New Page", "new");
    $admin_submenu_page['pages'] = array("All Pages", 'pages');

    $admin_submenu_page['setings'] = array("SMTP", "smtp");
    $admin_submenu_page['setings'] = array("Theme Options", "theme-options");
```

**This is the html part that renders that menu in the page**

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($admin_menu_page as $menu){
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="#">';
    echo $menu[0];
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach($admin_submenu_page[$menu[1]] as $submenu){
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="#">';
            echo $submenu;
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**This is what it looks like at the moment from the above code**
[image]
**This is how the end result should be like**

[image]

Comment: Not too sure what are you trying to achieve but from what I understood  the easiest way to go is create a menu as stand-alone include file and then you can include it in any script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to properly create submenus, you are missing brackets:

Instead:

```
$admin_submenu_page['dashboard'] = array("Home", "home");
$admin_submenu_page['dashboard'] = array("Update", "update");

$admin_submenu_page['pages'] = array("Add New Page", "new");
$admin_submenu_page['pages'] = array("All Pages", 'pages');

$admin_submenu_page['setings'] = array("SMTP", "smtp");
$admin_submenu_page['setings'] = array("Theme Options", "theme-options");
```

Do:

```
$admin_submenu_page['dashboard'][] = array("Home", "home");
$admin_submenu_page['dashboard'][] = array("Update", "update");

$admin_submenu_page['pages'][] = array("Add New Page", "new");
$admin_submenu_page['pages'][] = array("All Pages", 'pages');

$admin_submenu_page['setings'][] = array("SMTP", "smtp");
$admin_submenu_page['setings'][] = array("Theme Options", "theme-options");
```

Second on the render, change:

```
echo $submenu;
```

to

```
echo $submenu[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$main_menu = array() ;

$sub_menu = array() ;
$sub_menu['dashboard'][] = array( "title" => "Home" , "action" => "home" ) ;
$sub_menu['dashboard'][] = array( "title" => "Update" , "action" => "update" ) ;

$main_menu['dashboard']['title'] = 'Dashboard' ;
sort( $sub_menu['dashboard'] ) ;
$main_menu['dashboard']['submenu'] = $sub_menu['dashboard'] ;

$sub_menu['pages'][] = array( "title" => "All Pages" , "action" => "pages" ) ;
$sub_menu['pages'][] = array( "title" => "Add New Page" , "action" => "new" ) ;

$main_menu['pages']['title'] = 'Pages' ;
sort( $sub_menu['pages'] ) ;
$main_menu['pages']['submenu'] = $sub_menu['pages'] ;

$sub_menu['setings'][] = array( "title" => "SMTP" , "action" => "smtp" ) ;
$sub_menu['setings'][] = array( "title" => "Theme Options" , "action" => "theme-options" ) ;

$main_menu['setings']['title'] = 'Setings' ;
sort( $sub_menu['setings'] ) ;
$main_menu['setings']['submenu'] = $sub_menu['setings'] ;

foreach ( $main_menu as $key => $menu ) {
    echo '<li>' ;
    echo '<a href="#">' ;
    echo $menu['title'] ;
    echo '<ul>' ;

    foreach ( $menu['submenu'] as $item ) {
        echo '<li>' ;
        echo "<a href=\"#{$item['action']}\">" ;
        echo $item['title'] ;
        echo '</a>' ;
        echo '</li>' ;
    }
    echo '</ul>' ;
    echo '</li>' ;
}
```

Note that this solution serve only to submenu 1 to 1, for submenu N to N submenu you should optimize this script using recursion:

See -> http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.recursive.php